# Rails 4/Ruby 2.0 error while executing rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, execjs

I'm following a ruby on rails 4 tutorial on the internet. I executed the command `rails generate rspec:install` and i got this

`rails generate rspec:install`

```
/home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/arman/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require'
    from /home/arman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I don't know how to fix this.

OS: Linux Mint 15 on Virtualbox
Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.0

Comment: You're missing a javascript runtime, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392743/when-i-try-the-command-rails-server-on-a-new-project-i-get-this-error/18392781#18392781), or just run `gem install therubyracer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what you got in the output.

*Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.*

Hmm, sounds interesting. Let's follow that link.

*ExecJS supports these runtimes:*

- *[therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) - Google V8
  embedded within Ruby*
- *[therubyrhino](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino) - Mozilla
  Rhino embedded within JRuby*
- *[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)*
- *Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X*
- *[Microsoft Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k.aspx) (JScript)*

I think you should install one of these.

Comment: I'm installing therubyracer.It's now building the extension

Comment: Ok, please let us know in case of any problems.

Comment: I didn't noticed that in tutorial it's says about possible js runtime lack.And also had the links to fix the problem.Thank you!

Comment: Installing nodejs fixed the problem

Comment: I guess installing both _therubyracer_ and _nodejs_ is a bit of overkill. One of the should be enough.